# Compass change name of sprite generated images

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

I'm working on a project I've inherited.  Problem is, when compiler generates sprites, name contains some random string at the and, I want to change that to something like version of project, so for example if i have sprite of "home" I want to have home-v1, for version 1 and so on.

I've tried to edit config.rb and add some code there, but I was un-successful.

So what i basically want is this: When i run compass compile, to get sprites with name like "home-v1.png" and when i run compass clean, to clean "home-v1.png", Also i want to do something like this, if i change version variable, so for example its not "home-v1.png", now its "home-v2.png" all old sprites (home-v1.png") should be removed.

Comment: What's wrong with the cachebusting string?  It's there for a pretty good reason.  I am almost 100% positive that if it is possible to get what you're asking for, it will be more trouble than it's worth.  Also, there's a good chance you'll forget to update your variable which is why Compass adds on the cachebusting string for you.

Comment: Hello Cimmanon, thx for quick response, I've to follow convention of project when project is being deployed which is "spriteRootFolder-versionOfApplication", I've never used compass before, so I've little knowledge about framwork, i don't even know why chechebusting is there in first place. Sorry in advance for my English.